# Line number and column number in Text Widget

Tags: perl, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit, perltk

Is there some method which tells you the line number and column number of a **Text** widget in Perl/Tk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/SREZIC/Tk-804.032/pod/Text.pod), the widget has a method `index()` which returns the "line.char" of various positions in the widget. Pass it the name of the special mark "insert" to get the current position of the insertion cursor. Pass it the name of the special mark "current" to get the current position on the mouse.

Your question doesn't make it clear which of the two you want.

Comment: I want to get both, the line number as well as the column number. How do I extract both of them?

Comment: @LiamWillis Call it twice, once for each index mark that you care about?

Comment: @LiamWillis: Yes, I know. And the `index()` method gives you both of them. It returns both values separated by a dot - as I said. Have you tried reading the documentation? :-)